Why does Django generate extra queries for related fields?
I am using drf and django-debug-toolbar.
# model
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


# serializer
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ["id", "title", "description", "owner"]



view
class ItemViewSet(ModelViewSet): queryset = Item.objects.all()
serializer_class = ItemSerializer


And I noticed this extra query that gets generated and I don't know why.
SELECT "marketplace_user"."id",
       "marketplace_user"."password",
       "marketplace_user"."last_login",
       "marketplace_user"."is_superuser",
       "marketplace_user"."first_name",
       "marketplace_user"."last_name",
       "marketplace_user"."is_staff",
       "marketplace_user"."is_active",
       "marketplace_user"."date_joined",
       "marketplace_user"."email"
  FROM "marketplace_user"
 LIMIT 1000

Can someone help me to figure this out?

if you do not want it, just set related_name='+' in field attr.

Use .select_related(…) [Django-doc] to fetch the data of the owner in the same query:
class ItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.select_related('owner')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
If it is however the form that Django generates when you visit the HTML form, then this is to populate the dropdown, this is not part of the API logic itself.

That looks like it isn't supposed to happen.

Are you using signals in relation to the Item model?
Or do you have depth=1 on the serializer?
Or does your view (or serializer) call item.owner in any way?

All of those would explain why that extra query is generated.
The LIMIT 1000 clause is added by djangorestframework, where 1000 items is the default setting when fetching data across related fields.

No , I am not using signal and depth=1.
but if , i use item.owner  it should only generate extra query to fetch owner detail  . I dont't get why ,that 1000 limit query is generated.

Maybe you can clarify what your question is really about. Is it about LIMIT 1000, or is it about the fetching marketplace_user?

Please don't perform guesswork in the answers like this. If the question is lacking debugging details, simply vote to close it for the same and use the comments to ask for clarifications.
